# Keyboard dismiss automatically when search a place using PlaceAutocompleteFragment in Google place API

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-places-api

How to dismiss Keyboard automatically when searching a place using PlaceAutocompleteFragment

I am developing an android application and using Google places API to display a list of places based on user search. 
I am using the Place Autocomplete(PlaceAutocompleteFragment) to accomplish this.

Comment: do you have some code?

Comment: add code.......

Answer (score 0):

Below is the static method which you can include in your `Utils class` to hide the keyboard whenever required.

You can call this method on your search completion, or when ever required

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager imm =
            (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Please note `imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow` may throw `NullPointerException` So add appropriate error handling to tackle the problem